# I am getting an error "No module named 'virtualenv.__main__'; 'virtualenv' is not a package " while building an apk file using buildozer

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, apk, virtualenv, buildozer

```
Exception in thread background thread for pid 29351:                           
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
   self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

RAN: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv --python=python3 venv

STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in 
    from virtualenv.*main* import run_with_catch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv.*main*'; 'virtualenv' is not a package**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

Did you install virtualenv, when not consider installing it with

```
pip3 install --user virtualenv
```

You can remove --user when you are in a virtual environment already

Comment: Thanks, But I am still getting the same error. and on installing it says "requirement already satisfied".

Comment: I'm also getting this error. Were you able to solve this?